# WPF DI Service Locator

Tags: wpf, dependency-injection, service-locator

So I'm looking for some clarification how it would be possible to remove the service locator from my application.

I have a ViewManagerService that is responsible for knowing which view is active, which views are open and creating a new view.

Currently my ViewModels get an IViewManagerService injected into them via constructor injection. These ViewModels expose ICommands that when invoked can then make a call to

```
viewManager.Transition("MyCoolView", somePrimaryKey);
```

The ViewManagerService then uses a service locator to look up and instantiate a new view with the key "MyCoolView". The reason for using a key string is so I can decouple the View from the ViewModels. I would like to keep the ViewManagerService generic enough so I can use it for other apps, so I don't want it to depend on a specific IAbstractFactory interface.

Any tips/suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of magic strings completely by using WPF's **data templating** engine. The best way to do that is to use the [MVVM pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx). It's orthogonal to DI, but a great enabler.

Once you've made that transition, you can have a pure DI architecture without having to rely on the [Service Locator anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx).

Comment: Currently my service locator takes in the "magic string" does a look up and instantiates a view. It then instantiates a specific ViewModel for that view and set's it to the DataContext. (Using windsor). It then calls the Load(primaryKey) function on the view model. If I was to use the data templating engine I essentially have a ContentPresenter that has it's DataContext set to the specific ViewModel I'm looking at right ? Would I then new up the ViewModel I want to transition to by supplying all of it's constructor args (IViewManagerService, etc) or would I atchitect this a different way ?

Comment: Yes, you can new new up the ViewModel directly, or, for greater decoupling, use an Abstract Factory. I'd tend to prefer the latter.

Comment: I'll give it a shot! Looking into the TypedFactoryFacility which seems really cool. Going to be a major rewrite but I think it's for the best. Thanks a lot, I will definitely grab your book when it's out :)

Comment: Yes, Abstract Factories implemented by the TypedFactoryFacility is a very cool combo :)

Comment: I just made all the changes and my code is nice and sexy now. Thanks again! BTW looking forward to getting your book.